# finding location java_home in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java, jre

I need help finding the location of my java_home/bin, or if it even exists. If it doesn't, what more do I need to install?

I am following some [installation directions](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/release-note/flex-4-6-sdk-release.html), and one of the steps says:

> Ensure that the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is installed on the computer and that the java_home/bin directory is defined in the system path.

I can't even find the path of java_home. Disregarding the directions for other OS, [this](http://sbndev.astro.umd.edu/wiki/Finding_and_Setting_JAVA_HOME) is the closest I've come to finding something helpful.

However, when I type the prescribed command, `echo %java_home%` it just returns `%java_home%` as a string, percent signs and all. When I try `% java -version` down further in the page, it tells me %java isn't a recognized command, program, or batch file.

I have Java 8 Update 60 installed, I can see it in my list of programs I can uninstall. From the quote though, I have in mind that if I have a JRE installed, then java_home\bin exists. However, I've had File Explorer search very nearly the entire computer, and found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I need help finding the location of my java_home/bin

- "Start" > "Control Panel" > "Java".
- Select "Java" tab.

  [image]
- Click "View"
- Look in the "Path" column for version of the JRE you have installed.

  [image]

In the above example the "Path" contains:

```
C:\apps\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

`JAVA_HOME` should point to the root directory of the Java installation, 
so in this case:

```
C:\apps\jdk
```

And the `PATH` should contain `JAVA_HOME\bin`, in this case:

```
C:\apps\jdk\bin
```

From a command prompt we can set these values using the following commands:

```
setx JAVA_HOME C:\apps\jdk
setx PATH C:\apps\jdk\bin;%PATH%
```

Notes:

- Modify the above commands as appropriate for your Java installation.
- These are `System` not `User` environment variables.

See [Installing the JDK Software](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDEBCCJ) and [Setting JAVA_HOME and PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for more information.

Comment: What's it mean if it does nothing when I click on Java from the Control Panel?

Comment: whatever the reason, uninstalling/reinstalling fixed it. In case it matters, I now have version 8, update 111

Comment: I suspect you meant setx PATH C:\apps\jdk\bin

Comment: @donutguy640 Well spotted. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 0):

On your keyboard click the windows key and q and search java.
Then in the apps section next to about java click the arrow and click open file location.
You are here at the file location

If this does not work for you you maybe don't have windows or you have an old version of it or if you have windows and the latest version of windows then I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: oh yeah and right click it and click open file location