# Storing the value from a command into a variable in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I would like to check if a java file exists on the PC and if it does, get the path of the file (excluding the filename) and use it in a variable. I need to do this using a batch file.

I have gotten as far as the following command which displays the full path of the `.exe` file:

```
for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

The result being:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

However, I'm unable to proceed further, as I need to extract the path, excluding the filename. Alternatively, there might be a command which just returns the path of the folder.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: `for %i in (java.exe) do (set JAVAPATH=%~$PATH:i) && echo %JAVAPATH:~0,-8%` or simply `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~dp$PATH:i`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, let me check and get back to you.

Comment: @Akina In my batch file i tried like you said but its giving below error. this is the content in batch file; @ : SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
@ for %i in (java.exe) do (set JAVA_HOME=%~$PATH:i) && echo %JAVA_HOME:~0,-8%......Here i dont know what will be name for java directory thus i want to get it through this command and then i can look for java/javaw.exe.....This is the error message....~$PATH:i) was unexpected at this time.

Comment: 1) Check in a command line, not in a batch. 2) Do not forget to quote/duplicate percent signs in a batch. 3) Try second variant I have posted: `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo. %~dp$PATH:i`.

Comment: @Akina, Thanks for your reply, I had to make this work in batch file. But anyway I have used this link to resolve the issue. https://superuser.com/questions/1148677/finding-location-java-home-in-windows-10

Comment: I used below link to resolve this issue. Thanks. https://superuser.com/questions/1148677/finding-location-java-home-in-windows-10

Comment: Do not forget the PATH value can be altered freely so the result may became wrong or empty. I'd recommend to use some more stable method to find Java path - take it from a registry, for example.

Comment: @Akina can you please provide some examples so that i can go through the same.